# In makefile how to compare time stamps of the same file before and after changing it by shell command?

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, timestamp

First,this makefile dose not work

```
all:
    A=$(shell stat -c %Y test1);\
    echo "A is $$A";\
    touch test1;\
    B=$(shell stat -c %Y test1);\
    echo "B is $$B";\
    if (($$A<$$B)); then echo true; fi
```

output in shell:

```
$ make
A=1513082575;\
echo "A is $A";\
touch test1;\
B=1513082575;\
echo "B is $B";\
if (($A<$B)); then echo true; fi
A is 1513082575
B is 1513082575
```

the time is not changed, I think `touch test1` is just executed after `A=$(shell stat -c %Y test1);` and `B=$(shell stat -c %Y test1);`

and this one seems works:

```
all:
    A=$(shell stat -c %Y test1);\
    echo "A is $$A";\
    C=$(shell touch test1);\
    B=$(shell stat -c %Y test1);\
    echo "B is $$B";\
    if (($$A<$$B)); then echo true; fi
```

output in shell:

```
$ make
A=1513083955;\
echo "A is $A";\
C=;\
B=1513084224;\
echo "B is $B";\
if (($A<$B)); then echo true; fi
A is 1513083955
B is 1513084224
true
```

but `$(shell touch test1)` is not I want, is there any other way to implement this feature?

Comment: Please [format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) your question properly.

Comment: Thanks to SriniV for helping to format!

Comment: Thanks to Renaud for formating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$(shell...)` in your recipe are expanded by make **before** the recipe is actually passed to the shell. So, if a file named `test1` exists and its timestamp is `1513082575`, make first expands your recipe as:

```
A=1513082575;\
echo "A is $A";\
touch test1;\
B=1513082575;\
echo "B is $B";\
if (($A<$B)); then echo true; fi
```

which, when executed by the shell gives the result you got. If you really want the timestamps to be taken by your recipe, do not use `$(shell...)`:

```
all:
    A=$$(stat -c %Y test1);\
    echo "A is $$A";\
    touch test1;\
    B=$$(stat -c %Y test1);\
    echo "B is $$B";\
    if ((A<B)); then echo true; fi
```

Note 1: escape the expansion by make of the `$` you want to preserve for the shell by doubling them (`$$`).

Note 2: from the arithmetic evaluation section of the bash manual:

> Within an expression, shell variables may also be referenced by name
>   without using the parameter expansion syntax.

So, in bash, `if((A<B))...` does the same as `if(($A<$B))...` and is preferable because:

- escaping the `$` in the recipe is not needed,
- you do not need to pay attention to exotic values of your shell variables (blanks, quoting...).

Comment: thank you! it just works,solved my problem for optimizing make of an old project.

Answer (score 0):

SriniV,it works just add some  $ in your answer and then place it in makefile,Thank you!

```
 all:
    A=$$(stat -c %Y test1);\
    echo "A is $$A";\
   touch test1;\
   B=$$(stat -c %Y test1);\
   echo "B is $$B";\
   if (($$A<$$B)); then echo true; fi
```